# InteliJ IDEA,create a Scala class,proper order

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am learning from Coursera tutorial,but my IDEA is different from the one in the course.This is the screenshot 
[image]

When I try to create class,I got this

[image]

What should I change to get object instead of class?

This is how my GUI looks like
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask to create a scala class, select the `object` from dropdown

**1) Create scala class**

[image]

**2) Select kind of scala class**

[image]

but you will have to add `main` method by yourself, or also can extend `App`.

```
object ExampleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

  }
}
```

Comment: Plese take alook at my edit,I have different options.

Comment: This is after you click the `New -> Scala class`, it will ask the kind of class you want.

Comment: Yes, I get it now,need to choose kind dropdown.

Comment: minimum(registration) = `$950` - which is a lot, http://event.scaladays.org/scaladays-chicago-2017

Answer (score 1):

When you open the dialog for new class, do not click "OK" and below the name of file, select dropdown "kind" to select object or traits.